# Default username when using TTY login

Tags: linux, arch-linux, login, tty

I'm a single user on my laptop and I want username to be automatically entered when trying to login to TTY1. I use Arch Linux.

For example:

1. Turn on computer
2. Linux boots
3. I enter password
4. I'm logged in at TTY1 and proceed to do my work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've done some research. I just needed to enter `systemctl edit getty@tty1`:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -n -o username %I
```

After that, just type: `systemctl enable getty@tty1` and that should be it.

For more information there is: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Getty